# Check if List<Dynamic> is contain a object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics

I have some object with different properties. And i want to store to List using `List<dynamic>` and i already did.

But i have some problem when try to find specific object what I need.

For example:

I have 2 object **Movie** and **Genre**

**Movie Object**

```
Movie movie = new Movie()
    {
        Title = Title,
        Description = Description
    };
```

**Genre Object**

```
Genre genre = new Genre ()
    {
        Name = Name 
    };
```

And i store like this :

```
List<dynamic> dynamics = new List<dynamic>();
dynamics.Add(movie);
dynamics.Add(genre);
```

**I dont know to check the list is a movie or genre**

I dont want use like `dynamics[0]` for get `Movie` object. because i have a lot more object than code below.

**I try to use LINQ but did work or i miss something**

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is splitting to two collections. If you can not split you can do it in runtime every time `dynamics.Where(x=>x.GetType() == typeof(Movie)).Cast<Movie>()`

Comment: `dynamics.OfType<Movie>()` would be simpler